# MFC C++ and MSAL

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Have a 20+ year old MFC C++ application and our security people are looking for better access controls.

So I am interested to know if anybody out there has any ideas how to best integrate a non .Net Windows with MSAL ?

Thanks

Nick